# Why am I getting this 'enum' is not a class or a namespace error?

Tags: c++, enums

I need call a method with this signature in my Manager class:

```
void createPlayer(Player& player, PlayerType& playerType);
```

I have a Player defined like so:

```
using namespace std;

enum PlayerType { FORWARD, DEFENSEMAN, GOALIE };

class Player {
  public:
    Player();
    void setType(PlayerType);
  private:
    PlayerType type;
};
```

This is how I try to call the method in main ...

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Manager.h"

int main() {

  Manager manager;
  Player player;
  PlayerType t = PlayerType::FORWARD;
  manager.createPlayer(player, t);

  return 0;
}
```

... but it fails to compile with this error:

```
Main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
Main.cc:12:18: error: ‘PlayerType’ is not a class or namespace
```

Any ideas?  Note: I cannot change the signature of the createPlayer method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to using Enums in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183008/how-to-using-enums-in-c)

Comment: do not `using namespace std` in header files.  It is bad practice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`enum` doesn´t create a namespace.

Therefor `PlayerType t = PlayerType::FORWARD;` should be changed to:

```
PlayerType t = FORWARD;
```

---

Notice that c++11 introduce `enum class`es, which have a namespace. Beside this MSVC has an extension which treats (regular) enums like they have namespace. So your code should actually work with MSVC.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately `enum` by default doesn't create an enum namespace. So when declaring:

```
enum PlayerType { FORWARD, DEFENSEMAN, GOALIE };
```

you'll have to use it like this:

```
auto x = FORWARD;
```

Thankfully, though, C++11 introduced [`enum class` or `enum struct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) to solve this issue:

```
enum class PlayerType { FORWARD, DEFENSEMAN, GOALIE };
```

You'll then be able to access it like you did:

```
auto x = PlayerType::FORWARD;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be in this line:
`PlayerType t = PlayerType::FORWARD;`

As far as I know, the scope resolution operator (`::`) is not valid on regular C++98 enums unless your compiler supports them through **non-standard extensions** (like Visual Studio). Therefore you can't use it to reference an specific value from the enumerator.

Also, C++98 enums have the problem of polluting the namespace in which they are defined which can lead to name clash. Luckily C++11 solved this introducing the `enum class`. For more information check Stroustrup's FAQ: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum

Answer (score 0):

add a static function say getForward:

```
class Player {
  public:
    Player();
    void setType(PlayerType);
    static PlayerType getForward {
        return FORWARD;
    }
  private:
    PlayerType type;
};
```

Then use it in main:

```
manager.createPlayer(player, Player::getForward());
```

This should work.