# Error in creating a new type in c++

Tags: c++, class, enums

I just started to learn c++ and i have the following problem in this simple code:

```
enum class color_type {green,red,black};

color_type color(color_type::red);
```

I get the error "color_type is not a class or namespace". My goal is to create a variable of type color_type that can only take values red, black and green. Could you please help me? Thank you

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error from your sample: http://ideone.com/WVjvKq ?

Comment: Looks good to me, by chance what compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: Double check spelling in your actual code. There are no problems with the code you put here :)

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238391/why-am-i-getting-this-enum-is-not-a-class-or-a-namespace-error

Comment: PhilCK, I am using code::blocks 13.12

Comment: That's your IDE. The compiler is listed under the toolchain in project options.

Comment: Did you enable C++11 with the compiler options?

Comment: @walter yes i now i enabled it and it works! tahnk you !

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like valid c++11 to me.

If your compiler does not support c++11 then you simulate an enum class with a namespace or struct like so

```
 struct colour_type
 {
      enum value
      {
            red, 
            green,
            blue
      }
 }

 //usage is like so
 colour_type::value myColour = colour_type::red;
```

It's not perfect but it keeps the enum in its own scope.

Comment: Thank you very much. I enabled the support for c++11 and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your compiler does not support qualified names of unscoped enumerators (I mean your post before its edition when there was shown an unscoped enumeration). Write simply

```
enum color_type {green,red,back};
color_type color(red);
```

Or you could use a scoped enumeration as for example

```
enum class color_type {green,red,back};
color_type color(color_type::red);
```

In fact these declarations

```
enum color_type {green,red,back};
color_type color(color_type::red);
```

are correct according to the current C++ Standard.

Comment: I think, c++11 has a require to specify `enum class`'s scope, is not it? It does not compile also on g++ 4.9.2 with c++11 so you may be wrong and I am right :)

Comment: @Victor Polevoy You may use qualified names with unscoped enumerators.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using code::blocks and the support for c++11 wasnt enabled. Now it works!